# Adding contacts to Exchange Server programmatically

Tags: contacts, exchange-server

how can I add contacts to the exchange server programmatically? I want to export the address book of our application to exchange, so all users can use the contacts in their email autocompletion.

I don't care for the programming language, but it would be good if I could access remotely from my linux box to add the contacts (maybe by LDAP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through the Exchange Web Services API.